# State change not making it to the child container

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

In my react native app I'm using redux to handle state transition of a `Post` object -- the state is changed by couple of child components. The `Post` object has properties like `title`, `name`, `description` which the user can edit and Save.

In the reducer Im using React.addons.update return new state object.

The main container view has 2 custom child components (wrapped in TabBarNavigator).

One of the child component has few TextInputs which is updating a state.

Using the logger middleware and console.log() I see the new state value in the  parent view's render() (via this.props.name) but not in the child view.

I'm trying to figure out why the updated state is not propagated to the child container. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Im at a point where Im thinking of subscribeing to the redux store manually in the child container but it feels wrong

my code looks like this:

- [MainView](https://gist.github.com/csandeep/200ce2b3d11562fb07c2)
- [Reducer](https://gist.github.com/csandeep/a50f74e88c33b8437fc8)
- [configure store etc](https://gist.github.com/csandeep/a636fbb51b24f1fa143a)

The MainView

```
const React = require('react-native');
const {
    Component,
    } = React;

const styles = require('./../Styles');
const MenuView = require('./MenuView');
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer';
import TabBarNavigator from 'react-native-tabbar-navigator';
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton';

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as PostActions from '../actions/Actions';


import {Details} from './Article/Details';
import {ArticleSecondary} from './Article/Secondary';
var update = require('react-addons-update');

import configureStore from '../store/configureStore';

class ArticleMainView extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        //var store = configureStore(props.route.post);
        this.state = {
        };

    }

    componentDidMount(){

    }

    savePost() {
        console.log(this.props.post.data);
        this.props.navigator.pop();
    }

    render(){
        console.log("ArticleMainView: render(): " + this.props.name);

        return(
            <TabBarNavigator
                ref="navComponent"
                navTintColor='#346293'
                navBarTintColor='#94c1e8'
                tabTintColor='#101820'
                tabBarTintColor='#4090db'
                onChange={(index)=>console.log(`selected index ${index}`)}>
                <TabBarNavigator.Item title='ARTICLE'  defaultTab>
                    <Details ref="articleDetail"
                             backButtonEvent={ () => {
                                               this.props.navigator.pop();
                                       }}
                             saveButtonEvent={ () => {
                                               this.savePost();
                             }}
                             {...this.props}
                    />
                </TabBarNavigator.Item>
                <TabBarNavigator.Item title='Secondary'>
                    <ArticleSecondary ref="articleSecondary"
                                {...this.props}
                               backButtonEvent={ () => {
                                                 this.props.navigator.pop();
                                        }}
                               saveButtonEvent={ () => {
                                               this.savePost();
                             }}
                    />
                </TabBarNavigator.Item>
            </TabBarNavigator>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        post: state,
        text: state.data.text,
        name: state.data.name,
        description: state.data.description
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(PostActions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticleMainView);
```

The Reducer:

```
import {Constants} from '../api/Constants';
var update = require('react-addons-update');

export default function postReducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case Constants.SET_POST_TEXT:
            if( state.data.text){
                return update(state, {
                    data: { $merge: {text: action.text }}
                });
            }else{
                return update(state, {
                    data: { $merge: {text: action.text }}
                });
            }

            break;
        case Constants.SET_POST_NAME:
            return update(state, {
                data: { name: { $set: action.text }}
            });
            return newO;
            break;
        case Constants.SET_POST_DESCRIPTION:
            return update(state, {
                data: { description: { $set: action.text }}
            });
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

render scene of the app:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.id) {
        case "ArticleMainView":
            let store = configureStore(route.post);
            delete route.post; // TODO: not sure if I should remove this

            return (
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <ArticleMainView  navigator={navigator} {...route}/>
                </Provider>
            );
        default:
            return <LandingView navigator={navigator} route={route}/>
    }
}
```

configureStore:

```
import { createStore,applyMiddleware,compose } from 'redux'
import postReducer from '../reducers/SocialPostReducer';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';

const logger = createLogger();

export default function configureStore(initialState){
    return createStore(
        postReducer,
        initialState,
        compose(applyMiddleware(logger))
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone stumbles on this question this is how I solved it. In each of the child components I declared a `contextTypes` object like so

```
ChildComponentView.contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

to access the current state in the child component

```
let {store} = this.context;
store.getState();
```

Comment: This doesn’t look right. You should almost never use `contextTypes` or `store.getState()` in a React + Redux app — `connect()` takes care of these, as well as subscribing to the changes.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t know React Native well but something that threw me off is that you’re effectively creating a `store` on every render:

```
    case "ArticleMainView":
        let store = configureStore(route.post);
        delete route.post; // TODO: not sure if I should remove this

        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ArticleMainView  navigator={navigator} {...route}/>
            </Provider>
        );
```

**Store should only be created once per application lifetime.** It never makes sense to create it inside `render()` or `renderScene()` or similar methods. Please check the official Redux examples to see how the store is typically created.

Another problem is that you don’t show how you update the data, which child component doesn’t get updated, when you expect it to get updated, and so on. This is a lot of code, and it is very hard to help because it is incomplete, and most of it is not relevant to the problem. I would suggest you to remove all the irrelevant code until you can reproduce the problem with a **minimal possible complete example**. Then you can amend your question to include that example.